# Javascript Google Sheets API ошибка idpiframe_initialization_failed

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

На [сайте](http://kamahibe.beget.tech/) лежит такой код в index.php файле, я его взял из [примера](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js), подставил туда только свои CLIENT_ID и API_KEY:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Sheets API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
     * {
      font-size: 20px;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Google Sheets API Quickstart</p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize_button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout_button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // ID клиента и API ключи из Google Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = '42638290542-bg63148n2hjotbck0f19bn5lrd1fub9u.apps.googleusercontent.com';
      var API_KEY = 'AIzaSyDWFzE-jtc7a2Da4LnBWu1orBe8ulA2Sco';

      // Массив URL-адресов документов обнаружения API-интерфейсов для API-интерфейсов, используемых программой быстрого запуска
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4"];

      // Области авторизации, требуемые API, может быть включено несколько областей, разделенных пробелами.
      var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly";

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize_button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout_button');

      //  При загрузке вызывается для загрузки библиотеки auth2 и клиентской библиотеки API.
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      //  Инициализирует клиентскую библиотеку API и устанавливает состояние входа * Слушатели.
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Прослушайте изменения состояния входа
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Обработка начального состояния входа
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        }, function(error) {
          appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        });
      }

      // Вызывается при изменении статуса входа в систему для обновления пользовательского интерфейса.
      // После входа вызывается API.
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          listMajors();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

   // Войдите в пользователя после нажатия кнопки
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      // Выйдите из пользователя после нажатия кнопки
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      // Добавить элемент pre к телу, содержащему данное сообщение как его текстовый узел. Используется для отображения результатов вызова API.  @param {string} message Текст для размещения в предварительном элементе.
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Напечатайте имена и специализацию студентов в образце электронной таблицы:
       * https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
       */
      function listMajors() {
        gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
          range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
        }).then(function(response) {
          var range = response.result;
          if (range.values.length > 0) {
            appendPre('Name, Major:');
            for (i = 0; i < range.values.length; i++) {
              var row = range.values[i];
              // Выведите столбцы A и E, которые соответствуют индексам 0 и 4
              appendPre(row[0] + ', ' + row[4]);
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No data found.');
          }
        }, function(response) {
          appendPre('Error: ' + response.result.error.message);
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Такая ошибка показывается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я сделал в console.developers.google.com:

1. Я создал новый проект, подключил к нему API Google Sheets

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Создал ключ API и идентификатор клиента OAuth 2.0 типа веб-приложение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

API ключ у меня без ограничений

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Идентификатор клиента у меня типа веб-приложение и я попробовал вставить в `Разрешенные источники JavaScript` и `Разрешенные URI перенаправления` путь к моему сайту, думая, что мне это может как-то помочь. Но вопрос в том, что такого не делали в примере, там просто предлагают запустить сервер и всё будет работать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так? Я вообще сначала пробовал просто на виртуальном сервере это запустить и работать с этим, но я не понимал, как избавиться от этой ошибки, не имея пути к сайту

**UPD1:**
На сайте реальном это заработало(возможно, надо было просто подождать), но я не понимаю как это запустить на локальном сервере. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вы запускали на локальном сервере это

**UPD2:**
Я попробовал удалить текст с реального сайта и создать виртуальный сайт с таким же названием, как мой виртуальный сайт, на котором это заработало почему-то. Создал сайт у себя виртуально с названием google-sheets.ru, туда занёс этот код, добавил его в разрешенное и прошло уже 30 минут, но так и не заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, нужно было просто немного подождать и обновить страницу Жёсткой перезагрузкой с очисткой кеша